# Execute vim substitute command that includes '/' characters

Tags: vim

I have a java file in which I wrote /t, instead of \t, the proper notation of the tab escape function.  I want to use vim’s substitution feature (:s) but when I do something like this:

```
:%s//t/\t/g
```

I get the error message 
E488: Trailing characters

How can I write the command such that I can execute the substitution?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use backslash to escape the characters.  So:

```
:%s/\/t/\\t\g
```

You can also use a different delimiter like:

```
:%s@/t@\\t@g
```

Comment: I think you mean `:%s@/t@\\t@g` for the second version.

Comment: Thank you! One more question: what is the difference between backslash (\) and the @ delimiters?

Comment: @JohnJ.Kim Vim lets you use any single-byte character as long as it's not alphanumeric as the delimiter in pattern replacement. It recognizes whatever comes after the 's' as your chosen delimiter. There's no difference in using one over the other, except that when you have to escape slashes, using something other than '\' makes it more readable/writable.

Answer (score 2):

Use colons instead of a slash to avoid confusions and errors if what you want to look-up/replace has slashes. This way VIM will be able to parse the sentence correctly. 
Then you need to scape the back-slash otherwise VIM will replace `/t` with tabulations

```
:%s:/t:\\t:g
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape the forward slash in your search pattern:

```
:%s/\/t/\\t/g
```

or use another separator:

```
:%s;/t;\\t;g
```